# Terraform is not recognized as internal or external command in jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

I installed jenkins in local windows machine. Then i installed terraform plug in and did the config changed in global tool configuration in jenkins but when i run the jenkin pipeline i get 'terraform' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Code :

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
            bat 'terraform --version'
            echo 'Hello World'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

can you help me what i am doing wrong in this?

```
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\actimize2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Hello)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: No tool named terraform found
Finished: FAILURE
```

terraform config : 
[image]

Comment: You should probably look into using the Docker Terraform image as an `agent`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get the Terraform home using a tool command and then add it to the **Path** environment variable so that the shell interpreterinvoked by **bat** can find the **terraform** command:

```
def tfHome = tool name: 'Terraform', type: 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool'
env.Path = "${tfHome};${env.Path}"
```

In your pipeline, this would look like:

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
            def tfHome = tool name: 'Terraform', type: 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool'
            env.Path = "${tfHome};${env.Path}"
            bat 'terraform --version'
            echo 'Hello World'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can also use **tool** directly in the **bat** command (this is what I used to do when I was using Jenkins regularly):

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
            bat "${tool name: 'Terraform', type: 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool'}\terraform --version"
            echo 'Hello World'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can see a worked example in this [Automating Terraform Projects with Jenkins](https://objectpartners.com/2016/06/01/automating-terraform-projects-with-jenkins/) article.

Comment: I am getting this "ERROR: No com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool named Terraform found", any idea?

Comment: You'll need to install and configure the Terraform tool on the Jenkins Server first: "Adding Terraform to a Jenkins server is a simple as adding a Custom Tool.

First, go to Manage Jenkins | Global Tool Configuration screen on your Jenkins server (for v2.x). Under Custom Tool, select the Custom Tool installations… button, then Add Custom tool." from the linked article.